# Launching Windows 10 Maps Mobile not getting the parameter

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10, windows-mobile, bing-maps, windows-10-universal

I'm having trouble with the Universal windows platform. I'm trying to launch maps with a paramter to get direction in the windows maps app.

My code works well on the desktop version, but when i try in mobile it's not getting the parameter, it's only launch the maps.

Is there any different how to use the Uri scheme launcher?

Here's my code:

```
var uri = new Uri(@"bingmaps:?rtp=~pos." + lat + "_" + lng + "_" + name);

var launcherOptions = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
launcherOptions.TargetApplicationPackageFamilyName = "Microsoft.WindowsMaps_8wekyb3d8bbwe";
var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri, launcheroptions);
```

My reference is this:
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-maps-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its turn out that the var lat and lng on my uri is showing a wrong point because it is using comma, it should be using period.

i had to tweak it to change the comma.

```
lat.toString().Replace(',' , '.');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you misspelled the URI in your posted code. However, the URI you've posted is not right. The URI scheme of the Windows Maps app is

> **bingmaps:?query**

In your URI, you missed the `?` character and in my test, using your URI can only launch the Map app both in desktop and mobile. Once I add the `?` character, it works well both in desktop and mobile.

Comment: my bad, i missed the ? in my posted question. I can launch the Map in both mobile and desktop, but i don't get the destination parameter on mobile while in desktop is shown and the Map can show direction also the title

Comment: @HasyemiRafsanjani: Could you share the complete URI you are using? And also have you tested with the Sample URI in [Display directions and traffic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-maps-app#display-directions-and-traffic)? Do they work in mobile?

Comment: well the sample works well. and i think i recognize the problem. the lat and long parameter in my uri is using comma rather than period. eg 6,999 it should be 6.999. But i don't why this is happening, i check the model and my point is right using period. using toString doesn't help to

Comment: i have to tweak it change it to string and then using replace the comma to period. Thanks anyway Jay.